# How do i select all nodes and apply a css style to all of them, D3

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have an array of nodes. I wish to click a HTML button and change the style of all those nodes to that one style.

(For example: when i search for a node or click to select, i want to click the 'clear' button so everything resets)

Surely there's an easy answer to this but i cant seem to get it

```
.node.selectedNode {
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    stroke: #f00;
}

.node.unselectedNode {  
}
```

above is the CSS that i wish to alternate between

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add or remove a CSS class, you can use the selection.**[classed](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#classed)** function:

```
// Select all elements with the node class
d3.selectAll(".node")  
    .classed("selectedNode", true) // Add the selectedNode class to the selection
    .classed("unselectedNode", false); // Remove the unselectedNode class to the selection
```

The selection.**[on](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#on)** function can be used to listen for a click on a button, for example, for the clear button functionality, if you have button like this:

```
<button id="reset">Clear</button>
```

Then you can set the classed appropriately:

```
var unselectAllNodes = function () {
    d3.selectAll(".node")
        .classed("selectedNode", false)
        .classed("unselectedNode", true);
};

// Call the unselectAllNodes function when this button is clicked
d3.select("button#reset")
    .on('click', unselectAllNodes);
```

Comment: for some reason when i do this, the on click function at the bottom is not able to call the 'unselectAllNodes ? :/ am i doing something wrong ?

Comment: i put a console log within that variable to check if it was getting reached and nothing came of it

Comment: Have you declared `unselectAllNodes` **before** using it in the `on` function?

Comment: the only time ive declared it is as youve put above :/ is this all going global or in a function ?

Comment: Does it work if you use a function declaration, rather than a function expression? i.e. `function unselectAllNodes() { ...`

Comment: its not even recognising the clicked button
d3.select("button#clearNodesButton")
    .on('click', unselectAllNodes)
 console.log("clicked button");
 ;
added a console log to test but still nothing :/ i have tried it both function expression and declaration

Answer (score 1):

lets say your node is rect, you can use the .on('click') to

button on click ==> set_variable a scope higher
                ==> call D3 function to rerender

```
var set_variable;
$('#button').on('click', function () {
  if(something) {set_variable="classA";}
  else {set_variable="classB";}

  D3Function();
});
```

D3Function ==> ...

```
canvas.selectAll("rect").data(scope.input).enter()
  .append("rect").call(yAxis)

  .attr("class", function(d, i) { return set_variable; })

  .on("click", function(d, i){ 
  //d is the document, i the index
   });
```

....

```
$('#reset').on('click', function () {
  set_variable="";     
  D3Function();
});
```

Comment: doing this how do i select all nodes and apply a CSS style to them ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add classes to nodes with code like this: `.attr("class", "link")`.

For more context, you can see [the example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045). This particular example uses `svg.selectAll()` to select all elements with the link class, which may or may not work in your case. If you need more complex selections, the relevant documentation is [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_select)

As an alternative, the `.attr` method supports using a function to take action based on the data for a selected node. You can find more information in [the documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#attr)